# Is it worth taking action on questions incorrectly marked as a duplicate even though they should be closed for another reason?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question: [How to convert Object as timestamp to formatted date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579903/java-how-to-convert-object-as-timestamp-to-formatted-date/22579980?noredirect=1#comment34373209_22579980)

...was incorrectly marked as a duplicate; the linked duplicate ([Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/format-date-in-java)) does not contain the answer (and would not contain the answer in any case, no matter what clarification the OP gives, potential XY Problem aside). *However*, the question is also a poor question that *should* be closed for lack of sufficient information.

The concern is that the duplicate link is then misleading, both to the OP, and to anybody that may find the question in the future (although in this particular case, the latter seems unlikely). The other concern is that the description of the correct close reason contains links to Help Center documentation that could help the OP form a better question (presuming he reads them), and this information isn't present in the "duplicate" description.

What is the best way to proceed with questions like this (assuming the OP has been asked for clarification in comments)?

1. Vote to reopen, even though the question should be closed for a different reason.
2. Flag for moderator attention, requesting change of close reason.
3. Do nothing, since the question is not useful / informative as-is and will ultimately fade away and likely be deleted.

Comment: You could enlist the help of a few other users in one of the chat rooms (like the [Java room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java)), collectively vote to reopen then collectively close the question again.

Comment: The OP seems to be responding now though.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Given the additional information that the OP has given, the close reason should definitely be changed to "lacks sufficient information", not a duplicate. Also the description of the real close reason would potentially give the OP some links to read about how to ask a question properly. Unfortunately, in this particular case, the possibility of the OP getting a real answer looks pretty bleak. Personally, I am giving up on the question (dammit Jim, I'm a programmer, not a dentist!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I would do in a case where I feel I could help fix the question would be to:

1. Help the OP fix the question so that there's no reason to close it anymore.
2. Explain in a comment why the original close reason never applied in the first place or no longer applies.
3. Vote to reopen.
4. If this does not work, I'd consider contacting a mod.

It is great that BoltClock's a Unicorn is happy to change the close reasons but there does not seem to be a consensus among mods regarding this. And really, it seems to me that this is something that, most of the time, the community could take care of.

In cases where the question is so flawed it is not salvageable, I'd put a comment if I thought the OP was mislead by the reason visible on the page. So if a question asks for a tool recommendation but was closed for being unclear, I'd point it out in a comment but I would not seek help to change the close reason, no matter how much it bugs me.